# Iterate through results of SQLite query as input to subsequent query

Tags: sql, sqlite, loops, count, subquery

I have a single SQLite table that has the following fields representing metadata pulled from individual files stored on disk.  There's a record for every file:

```
__path      denotes the full path and filename (in effect the PK)
__dirpath   denotes the directory path excluding the filename
__dirname   denotes the directory name in which the file is found
refid       denotes an attribute of interest, pulled from the underlying file on disk
```

1. Files are grouped and stored by __dirname when created
2. All files in
   __dirname should have identical refid, but the refid is sometimes absent
3. As a starting point I would like to identify every __dirpath
   that has non-conforming files.

My query for identifying offending folders is as follows:

```
SELECT __dirpath
  FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT __dirpath,
                           __dirname,
                           refid
             FROM source
       )
 GROUP BY __dirpath
HAVING count( * ) > 1
 ORDER BY __dirpath, __dirname;
```

Is it possible to iterate through a query's results and use each result as the input into another query without resorting to using something like Python alongside SQLite? As an example, to see records belonging to failed sets:

```
SELECT __dirpath, refid
  FROM source
 WHERE __dirpath = <nth result from aforementioned query>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all offending rows, one option is:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*,
        min(refid) over(partition by __dirpath, __dirname) as min_refid,
        max(refid) over(partition by __dirpath, __dirname) as max_refid
    from mytable t
) t
where min_refid <> max_refid
```

The logic is to compare the minimum and maximum `refid` over each group of rows having the same dir path and dir name. If they differ, then the row is offending.

We could also use `exists` - which would better handle possible `null` values in `refid`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.__dirpath = t.__dirpath 
        and t1.__dirname = t.__dirname
        and t1.ref_id is not t.ref_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB.  I tried both, the first executes relatively quickly, but ignores records where refid is null.  The second runs, but it's very slow running against circa 600k records - indexing on __dirpath, __dirname, refid solved that.  The real table has many more fields so I replaced t.* with the specific fields I'm after.

As refid inconsistencies may arise from null or alternate values the second query produced the correct result listing all affected records.